# Issues sending http put request every 60 seconds to RoR app

Tags: c#, http, networking

Having a strange issue with a client side code that should be sending HTTP Put request every 60 seconds to my RoR website/app.

The issues is that The client side app pushes a few request up to the website(anywhere from 2 to 9 request). Then the client side code stops sending the http put request after the few initial successful pushes.

Information: Client side app is a C# windows application. website is running RoR 3.2.

c# code to send http put

```
    static void HttpPutRequest(string Json)
    {
        Logger("Sending JSON: " + Json);
        try
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://miningmonitor.herokuapp.com/workers/update");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                Logger("To URL: " + httpWebRequest.Address.ToString());
                streamWriter.WriteLine(Json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
                try
                {
                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                    var wRespStatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode;
                    Logger("Website return code: " + wRespStatusCode.ToString());
                }
                catch (WebException we)
                {
                    var wRespStatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
                    Logger(" Exception and Website return code: " + wRespStatusCode.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException we2)
        {
            var GetRequestStreamExp = ((HttpWebResponse)we2.Response).StatusCode;
            Logger(" Exception trying to setup httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream: " + GetRequestStreamExp.ToString());
        }
    }
```

client side C# logging statements

```
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"5953","rejected":"152","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.64","73.00","0.64","74.00","0.63"]}
To URL: https://miningmonitor.herokuapp.com/workers/update
Website return code: OK
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"5956","rejected":"152","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.64","73.00","0.64","74.00","0.62"]}
To URL: https://miningmonitor.herokuapp.com/workers/update
Website return code: OK
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"5964","rejected":"152","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.64","73.00","0.64","74.00","0.63"]}
To URL: https://miningmonitor.herokuapp.com/workers/update
Website return code: OK
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"5970","rejected":"152","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.64","73.00","0.64","74.00","0.63"]}
To URL: https://miningmonitor.herokuapp.com/workers/update
Website return code: OK
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"5978","rejected":"152","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.64","73.00","0.64","74.00","0.63"]}
To URL: https://miningmonitor.herokuapp.com/workers/update
Website return code: OK
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"5989","rejected":"153","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.64","73.00","0.64","74.00","0.63"]}
To URL: https://miningmonitor.herokuapp.com/workers/update
Website return code: OK
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"5995","rejected":"153","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.64","73.00","0.64","74.00","0.63"]}
To URL: https://miningmonitor.herokuapp.com/workers/update
Website return code: OK
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"5999","rejected":"153","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.64","73.00","0.63","74.00","0.63"]}
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"6009","rejected":"153","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.64","73.00","0.64","74.00","0.63"]}
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"6015","rejected":"153","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.63","73.00","0.64","74.00","0.63"]}
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"6021","rejected":"153","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.64","73.00","0.64","74.00","0.63"]}
Sending JSON: {"worker_user_name":"test:worker1","hashrate":"1.91","accepted":"6029","rejected":"153","hw_errors":"0","num_gpu":"3","gpus":["72.00","0.64","73.00","0.64","74.00","0.64"]}
```

from that point on its only creating that json not sending it.

server logs showing put request coming through

```
 Aug 13 10:31:52 miningmonitor heroku/router: at=info method=PUT path=/workers/update host=miningmonitor.herokuapp.com fwd="198.244.99.204" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=101ms status=200 bytes=2005
```

How I'm running this every 60 seconds is using a timer in c#. But Im just confused why the code stops entering the using statement and therefore stops sending the JSON string. You can tell this by the logging statements in the C# code. Im not really sure how the using statement works I just modified that statement from an example I found online to send http requests. So if someone could also explain the using statement that would be great.

Adding in the timer code.

```
    public void update(string user_worker)
    {

      System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
      timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
      {
          //query the miner for summary and gpucount information
          String SummaryQuery = QueryMiner("summary");
          String gpuNum = FindKey(QueryMiner("gpucount"), "Count");
          //String PoolQuery = QueryMiner("pools");
          int numgpus = Convert.ToInt32(gpuNum);
          //Array of strings to hold each gpu query
          String[] gpuQueries = new String[numgpus];
          //add the GPU queries into the array
          for (int i = 0; i < numgpus; i++)
              gpuQueries[i] = QueryMiner("gpu|" + i);

          //now add information specific to each gpu to a list
          List<string> gpuList = new List<string>();
          for (int i = 0; i + 1 <= gpuQueries.Length; i++)
          {
              gpuList.Add(FindKey(gpuQueries[i], "Temperature"));
              gpuList.Add(FindKey(gpuQueries[i], "MHS 5s"));
          }
          //set all the values that we have gotten from the queries
          this.worker_user_name = user_worker;
          this.hashrate = FindKey(SummaryQuery, "MHS av");
          this.accepted = FindKey(SummaryQuery, "Accepted");
          this.rejected = FindKey(SummaryQuery, "Rejected");
          this.hw_errors = FindKey(SummaryQuery, "Hardware Errors");
          this.num_gpu = gpuNum;
          this.gpus = gpuList.ToArray();
          //create JSON from the workerUpdate object
          string JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
          //send to website
          HttpPutRequest(JSON);
      };
     timer.Start();
    }
```

I caught the exception in the logs now. the exception is below. But not sure what it means.

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at MiningMonitorClientW.WorkerUpdate.HttpPutRequest(String Json)
 at MiningMonitorClientW.WorkerUpdate.<>c__DisplayClass1.<update>b__0(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Update:
So I've done more debugging and ive noticed that when I get the error my code runs until this line

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
```

maybe its trying to create a streamwrite and when I am requesting Stream I'm getting a null response? Not sure. But exception is saying something is null.

Comment: You have missed the most important piece of code.. Which timer of the many available in .Net are you using and how?

Comment: Putting the timer code in now!

Comment: The exception seems to be saying that you called the method `HttpPutRequest` with a null parameter. Put a check at the beginning of the method: `if (Json == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();`

Comment: I added the if statement and I still get the same exception as above. What is also strange is that once it gets this error then the error repeats non-stop until I restart the program but its wierd that I'm still printing out readable JSON strings(via the logs).

Comment: I am thinking something is wrong with this line  `using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))`

Answer (score 2):

You should put a try/catch block around the whole `HttpPutRequest` method body. The `httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()` may be failing or timing out.

Comment: I'm going to try that. I am hosting the website with heroku and I am wondering if they are blocking the request after a certain point?

Comment: Not sure I created the try/catch block correctly but updating the code in the main post. After running the client side app I saw the same behavior but with no new log information.

Comment: Actually, he should put a try/catch around the entire Elapsed event handler because `System.Timers.Timer` will suppress any exception that escapes the handler. If you want to know if exceptions are occurring, you have to catch them in the handler.

Comment: I actually dont think that will work because the timer runs forever.

Comment: You need to do `catch(Exception we2)`. It may not be a `WebException` in particular.

Comment: I'm not sure where to put it?

Comment: @ElliotWeil: The *timer* is persistent, but the handler only runs once per minute. If an exception is thrown in the handler and you don't catch it, the `System.Timers.Timer` code will suppress it. You *must* add a try/catch to your handler if you want to know if exceptions occur in there.

Comment: I got the exception I added it to the original post

Comment: I think this might be whats causing my exception is your original suggestion. What could I set  `httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()` to see if its timing out?

Answer (score 1):

This won't solve your problem, but it will help you to find out where the problem lies.

You *must* add a try/catch to your event handler. Otherwise if an exception occurs you will never know about it because `System.Timers.Timer` will suppress any exception that escapes the handler. In the code below, I just added a try/catch to your existing code:

```
public void update(string user_worker)
{

  System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
  timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
  {
    try
    {
      //query the miner for summary and gpucount information
      String SummaryQuery = QueryMiner("summary");
      String gpuNum = FindKey(QueryMiner("gpucount"), "Count");
      //String PoolQuery = QueryMiner("pools");
      int numgpus = Convert.ToInt32(gpuNum);
      //Array of strings to hold each gpu query
      String[] gpuQueries = new String[numgpus];
      //add the GPU queries into the array
      for (int i = 0; i < numgpus; i++)
          gpuQueries[i] = QueryMiner("gpu|" + i);

      //now add information specific to each gpu to a list
      List<string> gpuList = new List<string>();
      for (int i = 0; i + 1 <= gpuQueries.Length; i++)
      {
          gpuList.Add(FindKey(gpuQueries[i], "Temperature"));
          gpuList.Add(FindKey(gpuQueries[i], "MHS 5s"));
      }
      //set all the values that we have gotten from the queries
      this.worker_user_name = user_worker;
      this.hashrate = FindKey(SummaryQuery, "MHS av");
      this.accepted = FindKey(SummaryQuery, "Accepted");
      this.rejected = FindKey(SummaryQuery, "Rejected");
      this.hw_errors = FindKey(SummaryQuery, "Hardware Errors");
      this.num_gpu = gpuNum;
      this.gpus = gpuList.ToArray();
      //create JSON from the workerUpdate object
      string JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
      //send to website
      HttpPutRequest(JSON);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle exception here
    }
  };
 timer.Start();
}
```

It's generally bad practice to write `catch (Exception)`, but the design of `System.Timers.Timer` forces it. As the documentation says:

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0 and earlier, **the Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Elapsed event.** This behavior is subject to change in future releases of the .NET Framework.

That behavior has not been changed as of .NET 4.5.

If you don't catch the exception, then the timer will suppress it, meaning that you will never know that the exception occurred.

### Update

In most cases you should catch only those specific exceptions that you know how to handle. For example, if you want to catch `IOException` and `WebException`, you would write:

```
catch (WebException wex)
{
    // handle WebException
}
catch (IOException ioex)
{
    // handle IOException
}
```

As I said above, it's considered bad practice to catch `Exception`, because you probably don't know how to handle it and it's probably better to let your program crash with an unhandled exception than to continue on blindly in the face of an unknown error. But because `System.Timers.Timer` will suppress exceptions, you have to catch all exceptions in your `Elapsed` handler if for no other reason than to log them so you know what the heck happened. Or you may have some way for your handler to notify the main thread that things are out of whack and it needs to shut down. So in your `Elapsed` handler, you have to hold your nose and do what you normally shouldn't do. After all of the *specific* exceptions, add:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle all other exceptions
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me some example code. If I wanted to catch multiple exceptions can I have multiple catch blocks or can I just say Exception EX and it will catch whatever exception is thrown?

Comment: Got the exception finally! thanks for helping me. Adding exception to the original post